# Not able to show all data fetch from sqlite db into Expandable list view

Tags: android, sqlite, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am inserting data from .csv file into sqlite database. But when I am fetching data from sqlite & showing it into Expandable list view,it skips some row data and showing in Expandable list view i.e. Some data is missing while showing from sqlite to Expandable list view

**Main Activity**

```
   ` databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    childDataHashMap = new HashMap<String, List<ChildInfo>>();
    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
    //Group data//
    Cursor cursor = databaseHelper.getExpandableData();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Log.i(TAG, "cursor.getCount()" + cursor.getCount());
    do {
        Log.d(TAG,"Category "+ cursor.getString(cursor  .getColumnIndex("categorydesc")));
        String categoryDescription = cursor.getString(cursor    .getColumnIndex("categorydesc"));
        int categoryId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("CategoryId"));
        Log.i(TAG, "categoryDescription:" + categoryDescription);
        listDataHeader.add(categoryDescription);

        //Child data//
        Cursor cursorChild = databaseHelper.fetchChildren(categoryId);
        List<ChildInfo> childList = new ArrayList<ChildInfo>();
        cursorChild.moveToFirst();
        while (cursorChild.moveToNext()) {
            String businessName = cursorChild.getString(cursorChild .getColumnIndex("BusinessName"));
            phoneNumber = cursorChild.getString(cursorChild.getColumnIndex("ph_Phone"));
            String landMark = cursorChild.getString(cursorChild.getColumnIndex("LandMark"));
            Log.w("", "Category Child " + businessName);
            ChildInfo childInfo = new ChildInfo(businessName, phoneNumber,landMark);
            childList.add(childInfo);
        }
        childDataHashMap.put(categoryDescription, childList);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    cursor.close(); 
    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapterNew(this, listDataHeader,childDataHashMap);
    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

**Database Helper**

```
    public Cursor fetchGroup() {
        String query = "SELECT DISTINCT CategoryId, categorydesc FROM Category ";
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return res;
    }

    public Cursor getExpandableData() {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM Category GROUP BY categorydesc";
        return db.rawQuery(query, null);
    }
```

**Logcat output**

```
Number of Records(10600):  :: 11
MainAcitivity(10600): cursor.getCount()6
Category Hotels
         categoryDescription:Hotels
        Category Child GoodLuck
Category Restaurants
         categoryDescription:Restaurants
         Category Child ByThe Way
Category School
         categoryDescription:School
         Category Child Ornellas
Category Stationary
         categoryDescription:Stationary
         Category Child Venus
Category super shopee
```

Actual categories are 6 but it's showing only 5 of them.

Comment: Can you format question so we can read it post answer.

Comment: fix some formatting and remove some cruft

Answer (score 0):

Problem in:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();       
Log.i(TAG, "cursor.getCount()"+cursor.getCount());
while (cursor.moveToNext()) // ...
```

You are move cursor to first item, no gets data for this, move to next.
For child items - same problem.

Comment: i have replaced it with do..while loop now.It's working but it's loading only 1 child data per parent now

Comment: @AkankshaSawarkar please, update your code in first post